# How to access custom NMAVenue3dVenue created with HERE Venue Map Admin Tool with Here Maps iOS Premium SDK?

Tags: ios, here-api

Already done:

Step 1:
Create or edit NMAVenue3dVenue with HERE Venue Map Admin Tool

Step 2:
Get App ID, App Code and License ID with the same account that was used to create the custom venue.

Step 3:
Integrate data from step 2 into ios project

Step 4:
Make sure here maps SDK is loading without any errors

Step 5:
Restart Xcode and clean cache

Result:

NMAVenue3dService listener function `venueServiceDidInitialize(_ venueService: NMAVenue3dService!, withResult result: NMAVenue3dServiceInitializationStatus)` (with result online success) and `venueService(_ venueService: NMAVenue3dService!, didGet venue: NMAVenue3dVenue!, with venueInfo: NMAVenue3dVenueInfo!, with status: NMAVenue3dServiceVenueLoadStatus)` getting calls but always with an unexpected venue. (The coordinates for this venue are okay)

I was also trying to obtain custom created NMAVenue3dVenue by manually asking NMAVenue3dService for it to find with specific coordinates and radius or unique id. It seems like NMAVenue3DService is not able to find the custom venue.

Please help me to get connection between custom created private or edited public venue and here maps sdk ios.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the custom map being created is a image-based indoor maps , then it would not be available via the Mobile SDK.

Reference Documentation: https://indoor.here.com/#/tools/help-text-2

> Custom image-based indoor maps are only meant for testing deployment
>   and indoor positioning in HERE Indoor Radio Mapper. The image-based
>   indoor map will not be exposed to applications via HERE Mobile SDK.